# C# Open XML 2.0 NumberFormatId range

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Working with Open XML 2.0 using c# to parse large excel files.  Issue I'm running into is the cell I'm parsing does not have a DataType I then check the NumberFormatId to determine if it is decimal, number or date.  I'm looking for the exact NumberFormatId range for numbers/decimals vs dates.  They seem to be all over the place some numbers/decimals have formats of 189,212,214,305 and dates having values of 185, 194, 278 etc.  Does anyone know if the specification defines these ranges?

**Edited - More Information**

Below is an example of the number format of 194 from the style.xml file inside the xl folder.

The excel sheets are from different regions of the world so I'm thinking the number formats are different, but do they overlap?  Will numFmtId 194 be something other than a date on different culture settings?

Below is how I'm converting c.CellValues like "40574" to dates, but the issue is how do I know if "40574" is a date and not a number?

```
 DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(c.CellValue.Text));
```

Currently I'm doing this by checking if there is no DataType than check the CellFormat but there are issues when some of the NumberFormatId are not in my check.

```
    private Object FormatCellValue(Cell c, SharedStringTable ssTable, CellFormats cellFormats)
            {
                if (c.CellValue != null)
                {
                    // If there is no data type, this must be a string that has been formatted as a number
                    if (c.DataType == null)
                    {
                        CellFormat cf;
                        if (c.StyleIndex == null)
                        {
                            cf = cellFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ElementAt<CellFormat>(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cf = cellFormats.Descendants<CellFormat>().ElementAt<CellFormat>(Convert.ToInt32(c.StyleIndex.Value));
                        }


                        if ((cf.NumberFormatId >= 14 && cf.NumberFormatId <= 22) ||
                            (cf.NumberFormatId >= 165 && cf.NumberFormatId <= 180) || 
                                cf.NumberFormatId == 278 || cf.NumberFormatId == 185 || cf.NumberFormatId == 196 || 
                                cf.NumberFormatId == 217 || cf.NumberFormatId == 326) // Dates
                        {

                            try
                            {

                                DateTime dt;
                                dt = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(c.CellValue.Text));

...CODE CONTINUES
```

**Edit**

In my updated post I forgot to post the value I found in the style.xml file:

```
<numFmt numFmtId="323" formatCode="mmm/yy;@"/>
```

So with this my question would be how do I get the formatCode and parse it to determine if it is a date?

Below is the output from the immediate debug window of the numberformat 323

```
{DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat}
    base {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement}: {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat}
    Alignment: {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Alignment}
    ApplyAlignment: "1"
    ApplyBorder: "1"
    ApplyFill: "1"
    ApplyFont: "1"
    ApplyNumberFormat: "1"
    ApplyProtection: "1"
    BorderId: "64"
    ExtensionList: null
    FillId: "0"
    FontId: "83"
    FormatId: "37992"
    LocalName: "xf"
    NumberFormatId: "323"
    PivotButton: null
    Protection: {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Protection}
    QuotePrefix: "1"
```

Comment: Take a look at those page containing a table with integer values and corresponding formats: http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumberFormatId%20Lookup%20Table or http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/6/11/openxml-sdk-20-formatting-excel-values.aspx.

Comment: Do You want some more help on this or those links were enough to solve Your issue? If so, I could post it as a solution :). If you want some more information or are looking for something different, let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Need more information on this.  The provided links do not cover the formats I've listed in my question 189,212,214,305 etc.  I'm looking for a range for all dates vs numberics/decimals or strings.

Comment: Could you please post xml of the *xls* file you are parsing of a code snippet showing how you check the `NumberFormatId` property? It could be helpful.

Comment: I just updated my earlier post with more information.

Comment: I've added more information, took the previous things I mentioned and into an answer. I've described how to check formats defined within xlsx file. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Looks like the formatting for the xml I pulled from the style.xml didn't come though, so I just tried again. So if I look at the FormatId "37993" where would I look that up to get the actual "mm/yy;@" format. Then I'd have to come up with a way to check all cases of date formats.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. The format definitions in *styles.xml* file define both id and the format explicitly. So in case of custom format (with high ID values), in order to check what the format is, you should parse the file and extract it.

Comment: So using the open xml sdk there is no way to get the mask value from the inner xml of the formatCode?  What would be the best way to parse the style.xml file to get the mask?  I can't imagine having to programmatically convert the .xslx to .zip then extract the file, find style.xml then look up the formatCode from the xml.

Comment: I refered to zip to manually check it. You can get the *formatCode* value with OpenXML SDK. Check my updated answer for a code of a method doing this task.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Lists of formats ID values**

Below is the list of format options ([source](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table))

```
ID  Format Code
0   General
1   0
2   0.00
3   #,##0
4   #,##0.00
9   0%
10  0.00%
11  0.00E+00
12  # ?/?
13  # ??/??
14  d/m/yyyy
15  d-mmm-yy
16  d-mmm
17  mmm-yy
18  h:mm tt
19  h:mm:ss tt
20  H:mm
21  H:mm:ss
22  m/d/yyyy H:mm
37  #,##0 ;(#,##0)
38  #,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)
39  #,##0.00;(#,##0.00)
40  #,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00)
45  mm:ss
46  [h]:mm:ss
47  mmss.0
48  ##0.0E+0
49  @
```

Hower, those list specify only several formats. According to this post: [Reading dates from OpenXml Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655565/reading-dates-from-openxml-excel-files), format with ID value less than 164 are built in. You can also find a longer list of formats there.

**Checking formats ID values in xlsx file**

For formats with greater ID values, you can find their definitions inside the file itself. In order to see them, you should open it with a zip archive browser and find ***styles.xml*** file in ***xl*** directory. Alternatively open this xlsx file with [Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and navigate to that file's ***/xl/styles.xml/x:StyleSheet*** node.

In that section, you should be able to see formats defined in your document along with ID values assigned to them. The part with formats should look similar to this:

```
...
<x:numFmts count="1">
    <x:numFmt numFmtId="166" formatCode="yy/mm/dd;@" />
</x:numFmts>
...
```

Looking at formats saved here, it seems that id vlaues can be specific to a *xlsx* file, so probably the same ID value can be used to define different formats in two different xlsx files. However, for built-int formats they're predefined, so should be the same in all the files.

If you need any help with finding this formats in your file or additional information, let me know.

**EDIT**

You can also find some more information about number formats in this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.numberingformat.aspx.

**EDIT II**

You can use this code to get a dictionary containing all the formats defined within the *xlsx* file:

```
private Dictionary<uint, String> BuildFormatMappingsFromXlsx(String fileName)
{
    Dictionary<uint, String> formatMappings = new Dictionary<uint, String>();

    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        var stylePart = document.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;

        var numFormatsParentNodes = stylePart.Stylesheet.ChildElements.OfType<NumberingFormats>();

        foreach (var numFormatParentNode in numFormatsParentNodes)
        {
            var formatNodes = numFormatParentNode.ChildElements.OfType<NumberingFormat>();
            foreach (var formatNode in formatNodes)
            {
                formatMappings.Add(formatNode.NumberFormatId.Value, formatNode.FormatCode);
            }
        }
    }

    return formatMappings;
}
```

If you want to check if any of those is a date, I suppose a simple way would be verifying if format code (value in the dictionary created by the method I've posted) contains ***mm*** and ***yy*** substrings.

Comment: Perfect LukasZ M.  That should do the trick.  Really appreciate all the work you did on this.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. It was very helpful. No I can recognize date cell type in Excel.

Comment: What if I want a dictionary containing formats of each column present in the xlsx file?

Comment: If You want to get association between specific column and format used, You can probably use format id.

Comment: Microsoft link for codes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee857658(v=office.14)