# How to refresh Pivot Cache of Excel 2010 using Open XML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am making an **Excel Tool** using **Open XML** for some data processing. In this I need to **refresh my pivot tables** programmatically after inserting the data by refreshing the **pivot Cache**. I can do this by **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly** but it takes time in opening large files so I want to do this by using Open XML.

Do you have any idea that How can I do this using Open XML?

Please reply soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

using SDK see the answers here:
[Excel "Refresh All" with OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903697/excel-refresh-all-with-openxml)

when directly editing ooxml to fill a template xlsx:
edit pivotcache xml file: **xl/pivotCache/pivotCacheDefinition*.xml**
add the property-value: **refreshOnLoad="1"**
to node: **pivotCacheDefinition**

```
<pivotCacheDefinition 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
    r:id="rId1" 
    refreshOnLoad="1">
```