# Unable to set refreshOnLoad programmatically

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've written some code that produces excel reports. These reports may include pivot tables. What I want is to refresh these pivot tables on load. I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670816/how-to-refresh-pivot-cache-of-excel-2010-using-open-xml) and set refreshOnLoad to 1 in pivotCacheDefinition1.xml, so that in now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<pivotCacheDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
r:id="rId1" refreshOnLoad="1" refreshedBy="Jacobian" refreshedDate="42481.890576157406"
 createdVersion="3" refreshedVersion="4" minRefreshableVersion="3" recordCount="109">...
```

However, when I open this report I get an error message which can be translated to English as "It is impossible to change 'pivot table' under regime of group change". I'm not sure what is the exact message in English - I could not find  anything similar to that on the Web.

Comment: The whole problem was in grouped lists - something I've not known before. The catch was that two lists were active at the same time. And all that resulted in this error message.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the following under the `ThisWorkbook` object?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

The Pivot Table is on `Sheet3` and the name of the Pivot Table is `PivotTable1`

Comment: Thanks, Brian! It's a very useful function.